# Corrupt MS Word document: figuring out *what* is corrupt

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a fairly long document (about 360 pages, approx. 2 MB in size) with hundreds, if not thousands, of tracked changes by several different reviewers. I would very much like to hide some of the reviewers’ changes and show only those made by one particular reviewer, but unfortunately the document seems to be somehow corrupt.

On a Windows machine, I can open the document and edit it just fine, but whenever I go to Review -> Markup Options -> Reviewers, the entire application grinds to a halt and crashes before even showing the list of reviewers.

On a Mac, I can’t even open the document—it crashes both Word (2011 and 2016), OpenOffice, and LibreOffice.

I’ve tried saving the .docx file as a .zip file and having a look through its contents like that, but the resulting document.xml file is quite big (about 37 MB) and [strains the XML readers I have available](https://superuser.com/questions/1240807/why-does-xml-editing-xpath-searching-use-such-ridiculous-amounts-of-memory) to the point that reading through it manually is not a practical option. At least I’ve been able to ascertain that document.xml *is valid XML* (or rather: browsers and XML readers don’t complain that it isn’t).

Is there some way of figuring out exactly **what** in a Word document has been corrupted, **without** losing all the tracked changes that are in the document?